# Block ICMP timestamp & timestamp reply with firewalld

Tags: centos, icmp, firewalld, timestamp

OS: CentOS 7.0

Per the results of a security scan, it has been suggested that we block ICMP timestamp & timestamp reply messages using the firewall ([CVE-1999-0524](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-1999-0524)). I've used firewalld to set up some basic IP filtering for SSH as well as allowing HTTPS, but am stumped on this one.

The only thing I could think of was `firewall-cmd --add-icmp-block`, but I can't find an `icmptype` that seems to be relevant to timestamp or timestamp reply.

The available types (`firewall-cmd --get-icmptypes`) are as follows:
`destination-unreachable echo-reply echo-request parameter-problem redirect router-advertisement router-solicitation source-quench time-exceeded`.

**How do I block ICMP timestamp requests with `firewalld`?**

Comment: This open CentOS issue may be related: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8330

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`firewalld` ships with a default set of predefined ICMP types you can use out of the box:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-icmptypes
destination-unreachable echo-reply echo-request parameter-problem redirect router-advertisement router-solicitation source-quench time-exceeded timestamp-reply timestamp-request
```

The parser (`/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firewall/core/io/icmptype.py`) is not limited to these types, though, and allows to be extended:

First, as per `man iptables-extensions(8)`, section `icmp`:

> icmp (IPv4-specific)
>          This extension can be used if `--protocol icmp' is specified. It provides the following option:
>
> ```
>   [!] --icmp-type {type[/code]|typename}
>           This allows specification of the ICMP type, which can be a numeric ICMP type, type/code pair, or one of the ICMP type names shown by the command
>            iptables -p icmp -h
> ```
>
> icmp6 (IPv6-specific)
>          This extension can be used if `--protocol ipv6-icmp' or`--protocol icmpv6' is specified. It provides the following option:
>
> ```
>   [!] --icmpv6-type type[/code]|typename
>           This allows specification of the ICMPv6 type, which can be a numeric ICMPv6 type, type and code, or one of the ICMPv6 type names shown by the command
>            ip6tables -p ipv6-icmp -h
> ```

The two types you refer are IPv4 specific, hence you should use the following to find out the appropriate names as recognized by `iptables`:

```
# iptables -p icmp -h | grep timestamp
timestamp-request
timestamp-reply
```

Now, if you check the contents of the `firewalld` package, you'll find where the predefined ICMP types are stored:

```
# rpm -ql firewalld | grep icmptype
/etc/firewalld/icmptypes
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/destination-unreachable.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/echo-reply.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/echo-request.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/parameter-problem.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/redirect.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/router-advertisement.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/router-solicitation.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/source-quench.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/icmptypes/time-exceeded.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/xmlschema/icmptype.xsd
/usr/share/man/man5/firewalld.icmptype.5.gz
```

If you check the parser referenced above, you'll see it uses the XML file name as ICMP type when talking to `iptables`, so you need to write two new files for the ICMP types you want to use using the ICMP types found above. User created ICMP types should be stored in `/etc/firewalld/icmptypes`.

```
# cat timestamp-request.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<icmptype>
  <short>Timestamp Request</short>
  <description>This message is used for time synchronization.</description>
  <destination ipv4="yes"/>
  <destination ipv6="no"/>
</icmptype>
# cat timestamp-reply.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<icmptype>
  <short>Timestamp Reply</short>
  <description>This message is used to reply to a timestamp message.</description>
  <destination ipv4="yes"/>
  <destination ipv6="no"/>
</icmptype>
```

You'll end up with:

```
# ll -Z /etc/firewalld/icmptypes
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:firewalld_etc_rw_t:s0 timestamp-reply.xml
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:firewalld_etc_rw_t:s0 timestamp-request.xml
```

Validate them using the provided XSD:

```
# xmllint --schema /usr/lib/firewalld/xmlschema/icmptype.xsd timestamp-request.xml
timestamp-request.xml validates

# xmllint --noout --schema /usr/lib/firewalld/xmlschema/icmptype.xsd timestamp-reply.xml
timestamp-reply.xml validates
```

Reload the firewall:

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

And finally add them:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-icmp-block=timestamp-request
# firewall-cmd --add-icmp-block=timestamp-reply

# firewall-cmd --list-icmp-blocks
timestamp-reply timestamp-request
```

You can check they have been added looking at the `iptables` rules directly:

```
iptables -nvL | grep icmp
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 13 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 14 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 13 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 14 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Types 13 and 14 are the newly added [ICMP types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol).

For reference, you can read the `firewalld.icmptypes(5)` manpage.

These ICMP types have been included [upstream](https://github.com/t-woerner/firewalld/pull/4#event-294161288).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @dawud! Unfortunately, it's not quite working on my system. After creating the new XML files in `/etc/firewalld/icmptypes`, they are still not addable with `firewall-cmd --add-icmp-block=...` ("Error: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: timestamp-request").

Comment: You need to run `firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: Great answer - helped me a lot - only one thing I would add is that the --add-icmp-block commands need (I think) an extra --permanent parameter (with a following reload).  Otherwise next reload wipes the rules.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this could be helpful, too, even if it is not done with `firewalld`:

```
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Comment: That only enables/disables timestamps, the OP wants to block that traffic.

Comment: Just to put a finer point on the previous comment, this answer disables timestamps on *TCP* packets -- nothing to do with ICMP.