# firewalld - how to block ping ICMP packets?

Tags: ping, icmp, firewalld

I can't seem to block ping requests to my server. I also followed the following post: [Block ICMP timestamp & timestamp reply with firewalld](https://serverfault.com/questions/677084/block-icmp-timestamp-timestamp-reply-with-firewalld?newreg=3bbbfc35767a47c7a1225eae75bb07cf)

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: echo-reply timestamp-reply timestamp-request
  rich rules: 

# firewall-cmd --get-icmptypes
destination-unreachable echo-reply echo-request parameter-problem redirect router-advertisement router-solicitation source-quench time-exceeded timestamp-reply timestamp-request
```

And I also did a reload (`firewall-cmd --reload`), but was still able to ping my server. I'm not sure what else I have to do in order to block pings to my server.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's considered very poor practice to block ICMP of any type.

Comment: I thought blocking ICMP packets are good for preventing some potential DDOS attacks or something. Why is it poor practice to block ICMP of any type?

Comment: Because ICMP is used by servers and clients to discover critical information about the path between them ([PMTUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) for instance), and by blocking ICMP, you're prohibiting that functionality. Blocking ICMP is even *more* damaging if you're using IPv6.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks; I'll remove the ICMP blocks then.